# Parametized thread, understanding lambda expression

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

I read the following code and would like to understand a bit more the lambda expression.

```
ThreadStart starter = () => Threads.QueryThread(tmpweb, LastExecutedate);
var thread = new Thread(starter);
thread.Start();
```

After reading [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397687.aspx), no argument is given (`() =>`) and the expression is the initialisation of a ThreadStart instance with an anonymous delegate of the static method Threads.QueryThread ? Is that right ?

Comment: Why don't you use `Task.Run`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there are lots of reasons to choose between `Task.Run` and `Thread.Start` - it *really really* isn't as simple as "use x" or "use y"; I could turn that around and ask "why use `Task.Run`?" - both are perfectly legitimate questions, that demand a lot more context about what is going on internally

Comment: @MarcGravell when the question is `how do Lambdas work`, it's very likely that a thread was used by default, or after following an older tutorial

Comment: I can't use Task.Run due to .NET version. However i'm interested in the perks and differences of each to learn how to do better choices later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with an anonymous delegate of the static method Threads.QueryThread ? Is that right ?

Not quite; it is a delegate instance refers to a method target that is implemented an anonymous method that 
in turn *invokes* the `Threads.QueryThread` method, presumably using a capture-context that provides access to `tmpweb` and `LastExecutedate` (probably via `this`?)

i.e.

```
class SomeClass {
    public SomeType tmpweb;
    public SomeOtherType @this;
    public void TheMethod() {
        Threads.QueryThread(tmpweb, @this.LastExecutedate);
    }
}
```

and:

```
SomeClass ctx = new SomeClass { @this = this };
...
ctx.tmpweb = ... 
...
ThreadStart starter = new ThreadStart(ctx.TheMethod);
var thread = new Thread(starter);
thread.Start();
```

Note that there *is* some scope in here for differences depending on **exactly** what `tmpweb` and `LastExecutedate` are - if they *don't* actually involve any captured context (all static, or everything is on `this`), then the compiler can do slightly different things as optimizations.

Comment: yes, tmpweb is a local variable, LastExecutedate a private property and the shown code from a method in the same class